# How can we do 10 requests with server code in 5 seconds?

Tags: java, node.js, multithreading, performance, asynchronous

Problems: imagining that you have a query. it takes 5 seconds to be solved. Your users want to request to your api (/test) to get result of the query. They request to your api same time. So if the number of user is 10, the 10th user will wait 50 seconds to get the response. How can they do in 5s?

Every programming language is ok.

example code with nodejs:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var query = function(){
  var timeA=new Date();
  var timeB=new Date();
  var timeC=new Date();
  var time=0;
  console.log('test',timeB.getTime()-timeA.getTime());
  while(timeB.getTime()-timeA.getTime()<5000){
    timeB=new Date();
    if(timeB.getTime()-timeC.getTime()>100){
      console.log(time++);
      timeC=new Date();
    }
  }
  return time;
};

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('finish with time '+query());
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: please dont screenshot your code, just copy/paste with format

Comment: If your request actually hogs the full load of the CPU for 5 seconds (which is fairly unusual), then all you can do is get more CPUs to process more requests.  There is no magic to speed things up other than making your request processing more efficient.  But, if (as most requests), much of the time processing a request is doing I/O such as databases, files, networking, etc..., then you can probably process lots of requests at the same time with proper async programming.  As your question stands now, it's undefined enough that it can't really be answered.

Comment: And, screenshots of code are considered a bad practice here.  They aren't searchable, can't be copied and pasted to work on or create answers, etc...  Paste the actual code into the question and format it as code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jfriend00. About my question, we don't need care about the query that is supposition. In the real world with any query it will take a specific time, so let think 5s is the time. But your suggestion is my idea, get more CPUs. How we implement the solution in nodejs or java? Nodejs is single thread. Java can be multithread but my computer has only  4 cores.

Comment: I've changed the screenshots. Sorry about the inconvenience. It's a 2rd times I post a question.

Comment: It appears that you don't even know what the code you posted does.  It uses node.js clustering which starts a node.js process for each CPU present in the system, thus giving you the ability to use each CPU and have multiple requests being worked on at the same time.  Since a given node.js process is single threaded, this is how node.js uses multiple CPUs. That is already in your code.

Comment: But a real world request that takes 5s to process will not actually use 5s of the CPU and thus a single instance of node.js will be able to be process more than one request at a time.  This is the benefit of its async coding.  It really isn't clear what you're asking here.

Comment: And, one can also "get more CPUs" by using multiple computers and using a load balancer or proxy to share the load between them.  So, if you had 8 CPU per computer and had 4 servers, you'd have 32 node.js processes all with the ability to process multiple requests using async I/O.

Comment: You say the query is a supposition, but it makes a big difference to node.js if the "query" is using full CPU like the mocked delay you show or if the query is more like a real world query that consults a database and does I/O and most of the time is spent waiting for disk I/O.  In those cases,  single node.js thread can handle multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: I posted wrong code that I added cluster for my code. 
Your solution is my thinking, we can use load balancer for the problem.
About the 'query', if  you make a query with 5s in DB in real world. I don't think with I/O async, the server code can response 10 request in 5s. Because CPU server for DB will run full CPU in 5s for a query. So what we do next?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some load testing, you can use :

- Apache JMeter : http://jmeter.apache.org/
- Soap UI : https://www.soapui.org/Load-Testing/concept.html (more graphical, more functionnalities & configuration)

Both can do X requests in X seconds to your REST api and give you some stats.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's cool. Let do test with your tool and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question whether the requests send in any parameters that make the request unique. If they are all making the same request (with no parameters or the same parameters), your code can check the following:

1. On receiving a request: Check if there is another query in progress that would answer the new query. If yes, add this requestor to a queue but do not resubmit the query.
2. On completing the computation of a query, respond with the results to all requestors who have made the same query (from the queue in item 1 above).

Does this approach make sense?